# Página de boas-vindas em HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Boas.

Antes de desenvolver um website em C# asp.net eu criei um esboço no Wix. Só que agora não sei como colocar a primeira página [deste género](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzXB6.jpg), ou seja, uma pequena janela (com o index por trás) antes de entrar no site.
Alguém pode ajudar? Tenho de criar uma view nova?

Comment: Por que não um popup? Você usa `bootstrap`?

Comment: Trabalho pouco com isso. Como funciona o popup?

Comment: é uma `html` que é aberto como se fosse uma janela, igual ao exemplo que você colocou. Bibliotecas/frameworks como `boostratp`, `jQuery` ou `Material` geral um *modal popup*, já pronto pra usar muito fácil. Veja uns exemplos: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/ e https://material.io/design/components/dialogs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara eu não sei exatamente como é a estrutura que vc pretende etc, mas aqui tem um CSS muito simples que pode te ajudar. O princípio aqui é que o btn Fechar na verdade é um `label` *linkado* em um `input:radio` que quando `checkado`faz a `div` que vem abaixo *sumir* com essa regra CSS  `input[id="rd"]:checked + div.bg { }`

Repare que ele tem uma animação que ao entrar no site demora 1 segundo pro modal aparecer. Mas se vc quiser tirar basta remover a animação do CSS, deixei tudo comentado. Repare tb que quando ele está ativo vc não consegue selecionar nada que está abaixo, nem clicar em nada (isso pro usuário leigo).

*Tentei deixar o modelo o mais simples possível para ficar mais fácil de entender.*

Veja o exemplo.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#rd {
  display: none;
}
input[id="rd"]:checked + div.bg {
  display: none;
  z-index: -1000;
  opacity: 0;
}
.bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  /* remover animação se quiser que ele aparece direto sem delay  */
  -webkit-animation: tempo 500ms ease-in 1s forwards;
          animation: tempo 500ms ease-in 1s forwards;
}
.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.box label {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* remover se remover a animação do modal  */
@-webkit-keyframes tempo {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes tempo {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- modal -->
<input type="radio" id="rd">
<div class="bg">
  <div class="box">
    <label for="rd">fechar</label>
  </div>
</div>
  
<!-- conteudo -->
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>100px</td>
    <td>200px</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit">
<input type="text">
```

Comment: @-webkit-keyframes tempo {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes tempo {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}               estes campos não funcionam se colocar o "@"

Comment: @M.Carreira na verdade esse é um "vendor" prefix para a animação funcionar em browsers mais antigo com -webkit- Veja nesse link que ainda existem outras variações tipo "@-moz-keyframes" e "@-moz-keyframes" https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: Vc tb tem a opção de não usar a animação caso não seja compatível com o seu projeto ou algum compilador esteja dando erro por causa do @. Nesse caso vc tira os @keyframes e quando o usuário entrar no site o modal já vai estar lá instantaneamente sem delay, sem o fadein...

Comment: já tirei mas mesmo assim não está funcionar, não sei porquê..

Comment: Não sei te explicar pq não funciona no sue projeto. Pode ser por causa do position, ou talvez a ordem dos z-index... Como falei esse é um exemplo básico. Talvez vc posso usar o conceito para aplicar na sua view. Tirando a animação não tem nada ai de CSS que não seja crossbrowser etc.

Comment: já descobri.. é por causa do "opacity"! Muito obrigado @hugocsl!

Comment: Opa, boa garoto! Espero que agora de pra usar o exemplo. Mas se não der existem vários exemplos de modais por ai, uns mais complexos e com JS, outros só com CSS como esse humilde exemplo. Mas boa sorte ai, qq problema me fala que se for do meu alcance eu te ajudo com o CSS

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77695/discussion-between-m-carreira-and-hugocsl).